# Pest test returns status 403

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-filament, pest

I am trying to test my Laravel Filament (V3) app with Pest. Fairly new to Pest so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong:

I have a User Factory:

```
public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => fake()->name(),
        'email' => fake()->unique()->safeEmail(),
        'created_at' => now()->subDays(3),
        'updated_at' => now()->subDays(2),
        'email_verified_at' => now()->subDay(),
        'password' => Hash::make('password'),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
}
```

In my TestCase.php the setup method is implemented, [as the docs say](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/testing):

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());
}
```

My ClientTest.php contains the following test:

```php
it('can render page', function () {
    $this->get(ClientResource::getUrl('index'))->assertSuccessful();
});
```

When I run the test, I keep getting the following error:

> Expected response status code [>=200, <300] but received 403.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, so to help others who might be experiencing the same:

I failed to implement the FilamentUser on my User model and give it the canAccessPanel() method, like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser
{

    public function canAccessPanel(Panel $panel): bool
    {
        if ($panel->getId() === 'admin') {
            return $this->hasVerifiedEmail();
        }

        return true;
    }
```